# Allignment disturbed while runnin in IE10

Tags: html, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9, internet-explorer-10

I have an web application which is running properly in IE9 and older versions. But when i run this in IE10 UI is getting distorted. Height of the controls are showing different from IE9. I tried to fix this by making sure that when it runs in IE10 let it run in compatibility to IE9 by placing the below tag.

But this is not helping. The issue is still there. Is they any specific changes needed to run in IE10. Can anyone tell me why the height of the controls like iframe going for toss. The whole ui is disturbed.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure i have a general idea, but can you show what your problem looks like? Also, if it's of any help, Have you tried using overflow:hidden css property for your divs?

Comment: I have a popup window which has 5 rows showing different sections (iframe). But when i open this, in case of IE10 all the rows will have huge height and i can see only 1-2 rows because the outer windows width has been set. In IE9 no issues.  And i have used overflow:hidden for the body. That is not helping.